# Node position in list

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

how to get the current node position in the list? 
Is there any access like $node->position?
I'm using Drupal 7. Thanks

Comment: In what list? Drupal has no positioning OOTB.

Comment: closed. i forgot that i can use theme('items_list')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you offered more information on what you are doing.  You could add a select field called weight to the content type that would contain a range of numbers like -100 to 100 and then create a view that pulls in content of that type and then add a sort criteria based on the select field "weight".  But we would need more information on what you are doing in order to give you a more accurate response.